# Magento checkout for guest users only

Tags: magento2, checkout, guest-checkout

I am looking for solution to remove or skip customer authentication on checkout and Allow guest to checkout.
Simple is that we need to remove the authentication step to login or register, any one can purchase as a guest only.

Comment: Juts check if configuration Stores >> Configuration >> Allow Guest Checkout is set to YES

Comment: Guest Checkout is already enabled or disabled but customer need to get rid of login/register on checkout

Comment: Did you try this option:
Set the "Enable Automatic Assignment to Customer Group" option to "No"

Answer (score 0):

I have tried several methods to allow only guest customers and remove the login functionality.

Finally I have found a solution.
In orders to achieve this functionality we have to override couple of files in our custom modules using require.js

1. **Remove Password Field and Message**
   vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/form/element/email.html
2. **Comment Existing Email check function**
   vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/form/element/email.js
3. **Disable Authentication Component**
   vendor/Magento/module_checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml